# SQL Server: check if selected date is older or newer than current date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime, stored-procedures

I am selecting data using the following stored procedure with dateDT being saved as datetime.

Is there a way I can use CASE to check for each of the selected dates whether it is older or newer than the current date and add a short text (e.g. 'past' or 'future') for this to the Select ?

```
SELECT      dateID,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), dateDT, 106) AS dateDT,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateDT, 126) AS dateDTShort,
            countries,
            regions
FROM        DaysFixed
WHERE       countries LIKE '%'+@selCountry+'%'
OR          regions LIKE '%'+@selCountry+'%'
ORDER BY    dateID
FOR XML PATH('datesDT'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('root')
```

Many thanks in advance, Mike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT      dateID,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), dateDT, 106) AS dateDT,
            CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), dateDT, 106) > GETDATE() THEN 'Future' 
            ELSE 'Past' END AS FutureOrPast,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateDT, 126) AS dateDTShort,
            countries,
            regions
FROM        DaysFixed
WHERE       countries LIKE '%'+@selCountry+'%'
OR          regions LIKE '%'+@selCountry+'%'
ORDER BY    dateID
FOR XML PATH('datesDT'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('root')
```

Comment: This is perfect - thanks a lot for the quick help ! I will accept as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the field is a date:

```
SELECT      dateID,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), dateDT, 106) AS dateDT,
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateDT, 126) AS dateDTShort,
            (CASE WHEN dateDT < GETDATE() then 'PAST' else 'FUTURE' end) as TimeWhen,
            countries,
            regions
FROM        DaysFixed
WHERE       countries LIKE '%'+@selCountry+'%'
OR          regions LIKE '%'+@selCountry+'%'
ORDER BY    dateID
FOR XML PATH('datesDT'), ELEMENTS, TYPE, ROOT('root')
```

If you *just* want to look at the date component, and not the time, and `dateDT` is a `date` and not a `datetime`:

```
            (CASE WHEN dateDT < cast(GETDATE() as date) THEN 'PAST'
                  WHEN dateDT = cast(GETDATE() as date) then 'PRESENT'
                  WHEN dateDT > cast(GETDATE() as date) THEN 'FUTURE'
             END) as TimeWhen
```

Note in these examples that no functions are applied to the `dateDT` column.  This is a good habit to get into, although it does not make a difference for a `case` statement.  When used in a `where` clause, however, it can make a big difference in performance.